# How does dual-wielding affect accuracy?

Tags: max-payne, max-payne-2

Researching weapon accuracy is not as simple as one might expect, the bullets never hit exactly where the crosshair is pointed at (barring scoped weapons) and there appears to be some randomization. If there are no drawbacks to dual-wielding, the player  should always carry two guns outside of specific situations (peeking around corners) as ammo is generally plentiful, especially in the sequel.

Comment: I've tagged both MP1 and 2 because the games are mechanically similar and use the same engine, otherwise I'd post the same question technically twice.